# Cleaner way of inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my script in my stored procedure

```
IF(@Param1+@Param2 = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable values ('value1',null);
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @TempTable values ('value2',@Param1+@Param2);
END
```

is there a cleaner way doing the insert without using if and else. I have lot of such calulation in my stored proc. So i wanted to avoid if and else.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is a problem? A IF THEN is not a big problem to calculate... Use a CASE ELSE will not give you better performances, just different code.

Comment: It really is much better to do it in 1 query. Think about what happens if the query gets really big, then it might cause a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to write this using `nullif()`:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT 'value1', NULLIF(@Param1 + @Param2, 0);
```

You should explicitly list the columns in an insert:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable(col1, col2)
    SELECT 'value1', NULLIF(@Param1 + @Param2, 0);
```

Comment: Cool...wasn't aware of the NULLIF function.  Seems like it could come in handy.

Comment: @user2366842 . . . It is a useful function, but admittedly, I use it primarily to prevent divide-by-zero.

Answer (score 4):

You could use case when

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES
  (CASE WHEN @Param1 + Param2 = 0 THEN 'value1' ELSE 'value2' END,
  CASE WHEN @Param1 + Param2 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @PARAM1 + @PARAM2 END)
```